# Creating a webpage using forms

Tags: forms, html, form-submit

Hi i'm creating a webpage for my school's newspaper/journalism club. to be honest i don't know if any of the club members have much html programming ability and when i finally publish this page, i don't want to have to teach them how to update the page themselves (i will still help i just don't want to have to update the homepage my self) so basically my question is: is there a simple way to create an html form(s) that can create an html webpage? and could it be made so it updates to multiple pages at once. Thanks!

oh also if it is not possible with html or html5 i'd appreciate it if you post which programming language it needs to be done in :)

basically what i want is a form for the title, one for the paragraph, maybe a couple for pictures and i want it to turn out in the same format every time.....

Comment: [Drupal](http://drupal.org) is probably the biggest framework right now. It might be too much set-up for your purpose, though. Also, I'd say it would be beneficial for those hoping to do journalism (after the demise of treeware newspapers) to learn HTML.

Comment: well yes... honestly i don't think it would be too hard to teach them, but the question i really want answered is how would i post to multiple pages at once. for example how would i post to sports and the homepage at the same time

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'd have to look at a CMS (content management system) like Drupal, Joomla, WordPress, ... (there are many many more out there)

These CMS let you create and update your pages in just a few clicks even without basic HTML knowledge!

Comment: Drupal sounds like it might be a bit too complicated to build and manage for their skill level. My suggestion would be Wordpress if they want to implement a CMS.

Comment: Thanks i'll check them out

Comment: Yes. I recently did a big research project on CMS and Wordpress would be perfect for this.